# character of ms-access not found on java

Tags: java, ms-access

I execute the following query on ms-access:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ([Ville].Localité),[Ville].Code_postal
FROM Client LEFT JOIN Ville ON Client.idVille=Ville.idVille
WHERE ([Ville].Localité) Like [Quelle ville?] & '*';
```

where * allows me to keep the field empty and still print results. I'd like to "transpose" the query on Java (Netbeans) but the '*' character is not allowed. Do you have any idea of how to proceed in Java? Thanks!

Comment: You could try using `%` instead of `*` as the wildcard character.

Comment: @GordThompson Indeed, it works thanks a lot !